# JAVA Apache POI Custom Format

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I am Using poi version : **3.14**

I access an Excel (**.xlsx**) file

```
this.workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(f.getPath()));
this.workbook.setMissingCellPolicy(Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
this.sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

Here is a custom format found in .xlsx file applied to a cell. I want to display the cell value in my code.

[image: custom format]

As you can see the cell value visible in file is "031642153283700100". Also when i clic on this particular cell, value is changing to "42153283700100" (data without custom format applied on).

**EDIT**

Original cell type is CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC.

[image: Original cell in .xlsx file] ==> [image: Clicked Cell]

---

How can i display the formatted value "031642153283700100" in java code ?

I tried :

- cell.toString() => "42153283700100"
- cell.getNumericCellValue() => "42153283700100"

With previous cell type conversion :

```
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
```

- cell.getStringCellValue() => "42153283700100"
- cell.getRichStringCellValue() => "42153283700100"
- Old HSSFDataFormatter with formatCellValue(cell) method => "421532837001000316"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For number formats you should use `CellGeneralFormatter` or `CellNumberFormatter`.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.format.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ReadExcelWithFormats {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");
   Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

   Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

   for (Row row : sheet) {

    for (Cell cell : row) {

     String formatstring = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();
     System.out.println(formatstring);

     switch (cell.getCellType()) {

      //...

      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
       double cellvalue = cell.getNumericCellValue();

       System.out.println(cellvalue);

       String formattedvalue = "";

       if ("general".equals(formatstring.toLowerCase())) {
        formattedvalue = new CellGeneralFormatter().format(cellvalue);
       } else {
        formattedvalue = new CellNumberFormatter(formatstring).format(cellvalue);
       }

       System.out.println(formattedvalue);

      break;

      //...

      default:
       System.out.println();
     }
    }
   }

  } catch (InvalidFormatException ifex) {
  } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }
 }
}
```

**Edit**

OK, let's have a more general example. The above will not work with dates (what I had known already) but also not with all number formats. The latter I thought the `CellNumberFormatter` should do but it does not. Unfortunately it will even produce errors with some proper number formats.

In `Excel` a number format can contain up to 4 parts delimited with semicolon. The first part is for numbers greater than 0, the second part is for numbers lower than 0, the third part is for numbers equal 0 and the fourth part is for text.

`format > 0`;`format < 0`;`format = 0`;`text`

Since the `CellNumberFormatter` does not handle this properly, we should do it before using  the `CellNumberFormatter`.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.format.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.util.Date;

class ReadExcelWithFormats {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");
   Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

   Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

   for (Row row : sheet) {

    for (Cell cell : row) {

     String formatstring = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();
     System.out.println(formatstring);

     switch (cell.getCellType()) {

      //...

      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

       String formattedvalue = "";
       String[] formatstringparts = formatstring.split(";");

       if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {

        Date date = cell.getDateCellValue();
        System.out.println(date);

        String dateformatstring = "";
        if (cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat() == 14) { //default short date without explicit formatting
         dateformatstring = "yyyy-MM-dd"; //default date format for this
        } else if (cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat() == 22) { //default short datetime without explicit formatting
         dateformatstring = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"; //default datetime format for this
        } else { //other data formats with explicit formatting
         dateformatstring = formatstringparts[0];
        }
        formattedvalue = new CellDateFormatter(dateformatstring).format(date);
       } else {

        double cellvalue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
        System.out.println(cellvalue);

        switch (formatstringparts.length) {
         case 4:
         case 3:
          if (cellvalue > 0) {
           if ("general".equals(formatstringparts[0].toLowerCase())) {
            formattedvalue = new CellGeneralFormatter().format(cellvalue);
           } else {
            formattedvalue = new CellNumberFormatter(formatstringparts[0]).format(cellvalue);
           }
          }
          if (cellvalue < 0) {
           if ("general".equals(formatstringparts[1].toLowerCase())) {
            formattedvalue = new CellGeneralFormatter().format(cellvalue);
           } else {
            formattedvalue = new CellNumberFormatter(formatstringparts[1]).format(cellvalue);
           }
          }
          if (cellvalue == 0) {
           if ("general".equals(formatstringparts[2].toLowerCase())) {
            formattedvalue = new CellGeneralFormatter().format(cellvalue);
           } else {
            formattedvalue = new CellNumberFormatter(formatstringparts[2]).format(cellvalue);
           }
          }
         break;
         case 2:
          if (cellvalue >= 0) {
           if ("general".equals(formatstringparts[0].toLowerCase())) {
            formattedvalue = new CellGeneralFormatter().format(cellvalue);
           } else {
            formattedvalue = new CellNumberFormatter(formatstringparts[0]).format(cellvalue);
           }
          }
          if (cellvalue < 0) {
           if ("general".equals(formatstringparts[1].toLowerCase())) {
            formattedvalue = new CellGeneralFormatter().format(cellvalue);
           } else {
            formattedvalue = new CellNumberFormatter(formatstringparts[1]).format(cellvalue);
           }
          }
         break;
         default:
          if ("general".equals(formatstringparts[0].toLowerCase())) {
           formattedvalue = new CellGeneralFormatter().format(cellvalue);
          } else {
           formattedvalue = new CellNumberFormatter(formatstringparts[0]).format(cellvalue);
          }    
         }

       }

       System.out.println(formattedvalue);

      break;

      //...

      default:
       System.out.println();
     }
    }
   }

  } catch (InvalidFormatException ifex) {
  } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }
 }
}
```

---

**Important note:**

This code sample is from 2016 and is for `apache poi 3.14`.

As of the current `apache poi` versions `3.17` and `4.x.y` this should not be used anymore. In current versions this is as simple as:

```
...
   InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");
   Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

   Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

   DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

   for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
     String formattedvalue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
     System.out.println("Using DataFormatter: " + formattedvalue);
    }
   }
...
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: I am facing similar problem with rules handling. Do you know any class name or a method i could use to find more about this in documentation.
Should i create a new post for it ?

Comment: You mean conditional formatting rules? That's not trivial. You can get the `SheetConditionalFormatting` from the sheet with `sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting()`, then loop through all `ConditionalFormatting`s and test if the cell, you have, is within the `CellRangeAddress[]` and if so, loop through all the `ConditionalFormattingRule`s and get the formattings which there are defined. Yes please ask a concrete question about this.

Comment: It should be noted that numeric types can be formatted as text. In addition to checking for the "General" format, application programmers should also check for the "@" text format.

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt: The new `DataFormatter` considered `@` text format. And my code only is for numeric cell types (in case `cell.getCellType()` returns `NUMERIC`). If cells are `@` text formatted, then `cell.getCellType()` returns `STRING`.

Comment: Maybe I should upgrade. The older version 3.8 is almost the opposite: if cells are numbers `cell.getCellType()` always returns `NUMERIC` even when they are `@` text formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
           row = sheet.getRow(RowNo);
           // RowNo on which Row cell should have appeared
           cell = row.getCell(CellNo);
           // CellNo on which Position cell should have appeared on Row
           cell.setCellValue("031642153283700100");

  // You could also get CellFormula by using cell.getCellFormula();
```

Comment: My goal is to display, in the terminal, the value "031642153283700100" (current cell value "42153283700100" formatted with its custom format described in the .xlsx file).
I am trying to find a way to gather format and cell informations from the workbook. I don't want to modify the current cell value.

Comment: @Geo For display you could try System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue()); In Case of numeric value you could use  cell.getNumericCellValue()

Comment: Could you provide information about .xls file for better help !

Comment: Original type found with cell.getCellType() returns 0 means CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC. cell.getNumericCellValue() returns "42155609022100" I'll add it to the list above. You can see i already tried cell.getStringCellValue() using cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) previously. The extension is .xlsx not .xls, matters for HSSF/XSSF usage i think. I will add some more picture to best describe the situation.